# Transforming between standard forms of linear programs?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

There seems to be two forms of linear programs that are given as the "standard form":

1. Maximize $c^Tx$ subject to $Ax \le b$ and $x_i \ge 0$

(for example, wikipedia specifies this one)

and

2. Maximize $c^Tx$ subject to $Ax = b$ and $x_i \ge 0$

(for example, MIT teaches this one)

I think these are suppose to be equivalent to one another in some fashion, but I don't see how.

Is it possible to transform one into the other and visa versa?  How?

Given a problem in form 1, how do you transform it to form 2?

Given a problem in form 2, how do you transform it to form 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $(1)$ to $(2)$, we add slack variable. $$Ax+sI=\begin{bmatrix} A & I\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ s \end{bmatrix}=b$$ and also $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ s \end{bmatrix} \ge 0$

From $(2)$ to $(1)$, we can write $Ax=b$ as $Ax \le b$ and $-Ax\le -b$.